# MariaDB Galera Arbitrator failing to sync with SSL

Tags: mariadb, galera, mariadb-10.5

So the scenario is this. I have already setup a 4 node MariaDB Galera cluster (10.5). I'm also adding on top a 5th Galera Arbitrator and everything syncs and connects just fine. However when I enable SSL on the cluster ( after bootstrapping it from scratch ) I'm able to sync the 4 nodes but the Arbitrator for some reason does not sync.

Interesting is that when the nodes are syncing they're outputting "connecting...ssl://172.31.0.4:4567".
However when the arbitrator is trying to sync it's outputting "connecting...tcp://172.31.0.4:4567".
Seems like it's trying over tcp for  some reason.

It's config is this when I start it up

```
    name:    garb
    address: gcomm://mariadb-galera-0:4567,mariadb-galera-1:4567,mariadb-galera-2:4567,mariadb-galera-3:4567,mariadb-galera-arb:4567
    group:   scluster
    sst:     trivial
    donor:
    options: socket.ssl_key=/etc/ssl/galera/server-key.pem;socket.ssl_cert=/etc/ssl/galera/server-cert.pem;socket.ssl_ca=/etc/ssl/galera/ca-cert.pem;socket.ssl_cipher=AES128-SHA; gcs.fc_limit=9999999; gcs.fc_factor=1.0; gcs.fc_master_slave=yes
    cfg:
    log:
```

It doesn't give me an ssl or cert error just timing out

`INFO: (8bef8261-9d27, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://172.31.0.4:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 39 rttvar: 19 rto: 200000 lost: 0 last_data_recv: 3500 cwnd: 10 last_queued_since: 3499991400 last_delivered_since: 3499991400 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0`

The `pem` files are exactly the same that I'm using across all nodes + the arbitrator.

I read in the documentation that I need to specify the `cipher` otherwise I'll be getting an error. I tried `AES128-SHA` and `AES128-SHA256` and not declaring it at all but still timing out.

Below is the wsrep provider options from the phpmyadmin from one of the nodes. The `cipher` seems empty but then again why is the arbitrator trying to connect to "tcp://" and not "ssl://" like the others ?
[image]

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a flag `socket.ssl` = yes that the options of `garbd` need which for some reason is not documented that needs to be enabled for the arb to try to connect via SSL.